# How do I pass a flag into golang using go test

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have a routine that I want to test, that I have to pass a flag into this test.  This is on Win10 using Go 1.20.4

This is the func signature:

```
func detoxFilenameNewWay(fName string) (string, bool) {
```

I want to pass a flag I call dots into the test code for this function.
I tried from within the correct directory

```
go test --args -dots
# or
go test . --args -dots
```

Or from the top of my source tree where the go.mod file is :

```
go test .\detox --args -dots
```

I get an error message saying:

```
flag provided but not defined: -dots.
```

But that flag does show up when I run the program using the `-h` flag.

What am I missing?

Thx

The code I want to test is here:
https://go.dev/play/p/p-YeGDk1KaM

BTW, the previous question's solution that's similar to mine, from 2014, does not work for me.

Comment: See this previous question on the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27342973/5728991.

Comment: Can you show the code where you define the flags, and the places where you call it ?

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350962/process-command-line-arguments-in-go-test